# How can I disable Previous button on start and Next button on the last slide in jQuery cycle plug in?

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I want to used jQuery cycle plug in for show some slides in my webpage.
I want to show 4 slides in a row. When user click on Next button, slides moves only one slide (in this case only first slide hide and past three slides and new slide will be shown).
So I want to disable Previous button on start and Next button on the last slide.
Automatically slide option must be disable and pagers are hide. Only Next and Previous button make movements.
How can I setup jQuery cycle plug in for this functionality?

Thank You for your support

Answer (score 2):

Check this out! You need this function:

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var Left = $(opts.prev); // Fetches selector from .cycle options (ex. #prev)
    var Right = $(opts.next); // Fetches selector from .cycle options (ex. #next)
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    index == 0 ? Left.css('visibility','hidden') : Left.css('visibility','visible');
    index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? Right.css('visibility','hidden') : Right.css('visibility','visible');
}
```

Then then call the function in the transition callback:

```
$('#slideWrapper').cycle({ 
    fx      : 'scrollHorz', 
    speed   : 400, 
    timeout : 0, 
    next    : '#next', 
    prev    : '#prev',
    after   : onAfter, // <-- right here
    nowrap  : true
});
```

Just to be clear. The above function uses ternaries. For example:

```
if(x == 1) {
    Foo = 1
} else {
    Foo = 2
}
```

Is the same as the following

```
x==1 ? Foo = 1 : Foo = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the nowrap option in your code for the slide show. Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#slides").cycle({
    fx:    'shuffle',
    speed:    400,
    timeout:    0,
    next:   '#next2', 
    prev:   '#prev2',
    nowrap: 1
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Rich